# Configuring application servers to run as service daemons?

Tags: java, services, daemons

Mac 10.9.5 here. I am trying to figure out how to configured my machine to run an executable (Java) app as a service/daemon, so that it is *always* running so long as the machine is on. Hence, this app needs to start when I boot up, when I come back after being away for a while ('waking up'), etc.

Say I can manually run my app (server) by running:

```
java -jar /Users/myuser/utils/myapp.jar
```

**How can I get `myapp.jar` to run as a service/daemon?**

Comment: Look at Apple's documentation e.g. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2083/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003794-CH1-SUBSECTION47  This is a comment as the question is a duplicate and I don't have time to search for it

Comment: Thanks @Mark (+1) if this question is a dupe would you mind providing a link to the question it is a dupe of? If that other question does in fact address my OS version as well then I will happily delete this question myself!